# How to Read/Open .apk file with MediaStore?

Tags: android, kotlin

Hy

I noticed that, Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() is deprecated, and after that I read a lot, and I found a tip, that I should use MediaStore.

So, a searched, but I didn't found, how can I get a downloaded .apk file.

Previously, I read the file like this from the Download folder, but in Android 10 I get a access denied exception

```
val existingFileMd5 = try {
                File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(INSTALLER_PATH),
                    INSTALLER_NAME
                ).md5()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Timber.e(e)
                null
            }
```

Can someone help me, how to use MediaStore in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the private storage of the application.
`application.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`